# About protected data objects in ADA

Tags: ada

I'm new to Ada but not new to programming in general. I have a problem with protected data objects. As I understood from examples and books is that you can make a call for a member in the protected data object just as you would with a task.

Here is my code :

```
procedure ass4 is

   protected type Signal_Object is
      entry Wait;
      procedure Signal;
      function Is_Open return Boolean;
   private
      Open : Boolean := False;
   end Signal_Object;

   protected body Signal_Object is

      entry Wait when Open is
      begin
         Open := False;
      end Wait;

      procedure Signal is
      begin
         Open := True;
      end Signal;

      function Is_Open return Boolean is
      begin
         return Open;
      end Is_Open;

   end Signal_Object;
begin

Signal_Object.Signal;

end;
```

However the compiler doesn't like the call `Signal_Object.Signal;` and I get the following error

```
invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
```

So what am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a protected type, not a protected object. Either change the declaration from

```
protected type Signal_Object is
```

to

```
protected Signal_Object is
```

or declare an object of the type

```
My_Signal_Object : Signal_Object;
```

and then make your call to the object

```
My_Signal_Object.Signal
```

Comment: Thanks, tried to follow examples online but it's better if i get a book covering Ada :D